# Tweaking scrollbar

Tags: javascript, css, html, shadow-dom

Is it possible to programmatically change scrollbar's properties? Let's say I have a long table, where rows loaded lazily, and I want to emulate "paging" using vertical scrollbar.

Finite number of rows and current position in the dataset are known, based on that can I change scrollbar range and thumbtrack height? Let's say it displays only 100 rows at a time, but actual number of rows in dataset is 10000, can I make scrollbar look, like the table has 10000 elements?

**Basically I want to control scrollbar's thumb height and position. Possible, no?**

I guess somehow I can hide the scrollbar and build my own `input type="range"` and position it vertically, but I'm curious if it's possible to tweak scrollbar directly?

Answer (score 0):

I do not believe it is possible as of today. (October 8th 2014)

If you use the latest stable version of chrome (37), the inspection tools do not show a shadow root for any scrollbars.  We can use this as proof that it is not editable as a majority of the elements are now implemented and can be customized by shadow dom can be viewed having a shadow.

[this gives an example of styling the video player.](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom-201/)
example link shows them actually styling an `input type="range"` element. (in case that is of any use)

This probably for 2 reasons.

## 1 scrollbar implementation and its look and feel is os dependent.

The scroll bar on windows is a different size than the scroll bar on mac.

## 2 scrollbar user interaction is also dependent on the type of device.

For example on macbook pro laptop the scroll bar is different upon having a mouse plugged in.
Android does not even show a scrollbar at all except when actively scrolling.

tl;dr
as of right now the scroll bar world is too fragmented for native scrollbars to be styleable by html.

Answer (score -1):

You could this with the [Mousewheel jQuery plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/mousewheel/), but it will only work if the user uses the scroll wheel.

I don't think it's possible to disable the user from manually scrolling by dragging the scroll bar.

You could hide the scroll bar entirely, though, by setting `overflow:hidden` to `body`.

Comment: I'm not asking how to intercept events from the scrollbar, or how to hide it. I'm asking how to change its thumbtrack size and position of the thumb. Visually make it longer or shorter not depending of actual height of the container, but just of any arbitrary size. e.g.: actual container height may be 2000px and I want scrollbar to act like container is 6000px tall.

Comment: and btw. making `overflow:hidden` makes the content totally unscrollable. That's not really what I want

Comment: Also wake up - its' 21st century. Even my 70 years old mother-in-law won't use jQuery plugins to solve her problems